# mm-is-menu class isn't being added, submenu doesn't work MMENU

Tags: jquery, wordpress, mmenu

I have worked with mmenu many many times before and NEVER had an issue with this great plugin.
But on new version (3.3.2) I have started facing problems.

The mobile menu works (it slides from left etc) but mm-is-menu css class is not being added by the javascript, as result I don't get any css, submenus aren't working either.

Environment:
- Working on Wordpress 3.6.1 version + Foundation 3
- JQuery 1.10.2
- I have no errors on console. No jquery duplicates, no problems on that side.

Structure

```
<html>
<body>
   <header>
       <a href="#mobile">Trigger</a>
   </header>
   <div>
          //Content
   </div>
 <footer>
 </footer>
    <nav id="mobile" class="navigation-main" role="navigation">
      <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

JS FILE

```
$(function(){
   $("#mobile").mmenu();
});
```

The navigation structure made by WP is the same the plugin requires, and it works with previous versions of it with the same wp_nav_menu structure.

I have been reading all the plugin documentation and everything I have is correct. I don't know what changed on the last version, maybe I'm missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: did you check console for js errors ?

Comment: I specified that in my description: "I have no errors on console" I don't have any at all.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a same problem but what i did was I just put the mm-is-menu class directly inside the nav element and it worked.. I had no choice that time and i used same wordpress version. i dont know what's going on

Comment: Yes I did the same thing but in my case several things were not working, I got some of the css working but many things didn't (sub navigation, etc).

Answer (score 0):

There's the option "isMenu" that you can set to true to force the plugin into menu-mode.

Also try the latest version (currently 4.0.4), it should be a lot better with both menu and non-menu content.

**Update:**
The option isMenu (and the class mm-is-menu) is deprecated as of version 4.5.0.
Now, all lists will be styled as an app menu except if it has the class mmn-nolist.

Comment: Hi Fred, I tried forcing isMenu. Version 4 solved my issue though. Thanks!